# Git::Windows: pull case sensitive files from remote repo

Tags: php, git, bash, github

In my remote repository I have files,
example,

`-account.php`

`-Account.php`

To see how exactly my repository looks like, [image: See]

I am now using windows git bash to clone/pull the files from remote repo.

While doing that only
`-account.php`
gets cloned, while
`-Account.php`
is being ignored!

How do I get both the files,

`-account.php`

`-Account.php`

into my local repository, so that I can delete them and make a clean commit of files with only one naming convention and eliminate the mistake I have done?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with git. Windows treats Account and account as 1 file. You probably should not have Account.php and account.php in the same directory in the git. Try to convince them, or fork it and change it in your fork. Or better: don't use windows

Comment: I know I should not have two files with same name (different case) in the same directory, I realized that pretty late after having done it. Windows did not think they were two different files but the git did.

Comment: I will switch to linux and correct the mistake. Thanks for the comment.. :)

Comment: Can't you just change one of them?

Comment: I changed the name from
`account.php`
to 
`Account_.php`
So when I do
`git status`
It shows me that 
`account.php` and `Account.php` were deleted and 
`Account_.php` is untracked. 
So I suppose I will be able to fix by committing this and then coming back and renaming the files again in another commit! Right?

Answer (score 4):

Since git is a unix based it simply a case sensitive software.

If you have committed a case sensitive files you will need to rename them. Using the [**`git mv`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-mv) command will tell git to rename the file while keeping all the history of the file

```
# "move" the file from the old name to the new name
git mv -f File file

# Add the file to the staging area
git add .

# commit your changes
git commit -m "renamed file..."
```

---

Git has a configuration setting `core.ignorecase`.
To tell Git to be case-senstive, simply set this setting to `false`:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```

---

#### Documentation

From the [`git config` documentation](http://jk.gs/git-config.html):

> `core.ignorecase`
>
> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable git to work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT.
>
> For example, if a directory listing finds `makefile` when git expects `Makefile`, git will assume it is really the same file, and continue to remember it as `Makefile`.
>
> The default is **false**, except [git-clone(1)](http://jk.gs/git-clone.html) or [git-init(1)](http://jk.gs/git-init.html) will probe and set `core.ignorecase` true if appropriate when the repository is created.